# web server unreachable

Tags: linux, centos

I have a VM Linux (CentOs) machine. From there I try to run a CLI but this error occrs: `request to https://XX.XXX.XX.XX/api/accounts/prelogin failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XXX.XX.XX:443`

Can someone help me to find out where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Either the connection is very slow/bad, or their is some problem with the server.

Comment: how can I check that?